# Property's derived class is discarded(i.e., replaced with the base class) upon XML deserialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I have a game data class that looks like this:

```
public class SaveGameData  {

    public virtual List<PropertyContainer> properties {get; set; }

}
```

And these classes too:

```
public class PropertyContainer {

    public Property property {get; set; }//Could be set to DerivedProperty

}
public class Property {
    public int BasePropertyData {get; set;}
}
public class DerivedProperty : Property {
    public int DerivedPropertyData {get; set; }    
}
```

And I'm trying to save/load this data between play sessions, I'm using XML serialization/deserialization for this process.

The problem is that, within the PropertyContainer class, a derived property is sometimes used in subistution to the Property class, something like this:

```
PropertyContainer container = new PropertyContainer();
container.property = derivedProperty;
```

When the container is serialized, the derived class and its special properties are also saved, no problem here.

Here's the serialization code:

```
serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(SaveGameData));

SaveGameData dataToSave = GetSaveGameData();
using (var stream = new StringWriter()) {
serializer.Serialize(stream, dataToSave); 
...write to file... 

 }
```

The serialization process seems to be working, as the derived class is being recognized and saved into XML file correctly, the XML output looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<SaveGameData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <properties>

    <PropertyContainer>

      <property xsi:type="DerivedProperty">

      <BasePropertyData>1</BasePropertyData>
      <DerivedPropertyData>1</DerivedPropertyData>

      </property>

    </PropertyContainer>

  </properties>

</SaveGameData>
```

But when the XML file is deserialized, all derived classes are discarded. Here's the deserialization code:

```
SaveGameData result;
string data = ReadSaveGameData();
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(SaveGameData));

        using (StringReader stream = new StringReader(savedGame)) {
            result = (SaveGameData)serializer.Deserialize(stream);

        }
```

Which means after loading the XML data, calling `GetType()` on derived properties(e.g. `saveGameData.properties[0].GetType()`, assuming the property is DerivedProperty) will yield the base class, i.e. `Property`; which, by extension, discards all DerivedProperty's properties. There's the problem.

P.S:
I tried adding `XmlInclude` attributes, but nothing changed:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlInclude(typeof(DerivedProperty))]
public class Property {

...

}
```

How do I solve this problem? Is there a viable alternative to my approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decorating the `Property` class with `[XmlInclude(typeof(DerivedProperty))]` should have worked. Indeed, without it, `XmlSerializer` won't even let you serialize a `DerivedProperty` in the first place!

The following program is a working example based on your code. Please verify that the console output is `True` on your machine as well. If it is, you will need to determine how the code differs from your original attempt. Then update your question so we can dig deeper.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string savedGame = @"
<SaveGameData xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>
  <properties>
    <PropertyContainer>
      <property xsi:type='DerivedProperty'>
        <BasePropertyData>1</BasePropertyData>
        <DerivedPropertyData>1</DerivedPropertyData>
      </property>
    </PropertyContainer>
  </properties>
</SaveGameData>";
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SaveGameData));
        SaveGameData result;

        using (StringReader stream = new StringReader(savedGame))
        {
            result = (SaveGameData)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(result.properties[0].property is DerivedProperty); // True
    }
}

public class SaveGameData
{
    public virtual List<PropertyContainer> properties { get; set; }
}

public class PropertyContainer
{
    public Property property { get; set; }//Could be set to DerivedProperty
}

[XmlInclude(typeof(DerivedProperty))]
public class Property
{
    public int BasePropertyData { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedProperty : Property
{
    public int DerivedPropertyData { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how this non-existent bug passed through me, but it sure as hell wasted my time. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to switch to the [`DataContractSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx).  Then use the [`KnownTypeAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.knowntypeattribute.aspx) to identify sub classes.

```
public class PropertyContainer {

    public Property property {get; set; }//Could be set to DerivedProperty

}
[KnownType(typeof(DerivedProperty))]
public class Property {
    public int BasePropertyData {get; set;}
}
public class DerivedProperty : Property {
    public int DerivedPropertyData {get; set; }    
}
```